# SQL select subquery runs forever when passing MONTH to sub query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

The purpose of this query:
contracts in the database have a start date, contract date and closing date.
When a contract goes pending, the contract date is set and the closing date is set to a around 40 days in the future. I need to run a query that gets the contracts that have a contract date in the past and closing date that has not been reached to find the number of pending contracts for that month. This query generate a report of pending contracts from the last full month and going back 12 months.

My thought is to get the last day of each month and count the number of contracts that have closing date > the last day of month and contract date <= last day of month

The following query executes in 51ms. the query returns rows for July

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59') as lastDay,
count(*) as total FROM contracts
WHERE L_ClosingDate >= DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
AND L_ContractDate <= DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW() - INTERVAL 2 MONTH), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
```

Now I need to run the query to get rows grouped by month, so I altered the query to the following:

```
select MONTH(L_ClosingDate) as m, YEAR(L_ClosingDate) as y,
    (SELECT count(*) FROM contracts WHERE L_ClosingDate >= DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(y,'-',m,'-',LPAD(1,2,'00'))), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
    AND L_ContractDate <= DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(CONCAT(y,'-',m,'-',LPAD(1,2,'00'))), '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')
   ) as total
    FROM contracts
    WHERE L_ClosingDate > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -2 MONTH)
    AND L_CLosingDate < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH)
    GROUP BY YEAR(L_ClosingDate), MONTH(L_ClosingDate)
    ORDER BY L_ClosingDate DESC
```

It executes forever...
I've tweaked it and found that the MONTH and YEAR 'm' and 'y' in the subquery is causing the problem. If I hardcode a date it executes as expected.

Expected output:

```
 Month | Year | total
  8    | 2015 | 74
  7    | 2015 | 87
  6    | 2015 | 45
```

I'm working on getting some sample data

Is there another way to perform the group by query?

Comment: Is there some non-obvious reason the count cannot be in the outer query (dropping the subquery entirely)?

Comment: Looks like a Mysql question, why do you have `sql-server` tagged?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data and expected output? That would make it easier to help.

Comment: @FutbolFan - Sorry, It was a suggested tag.

Comment: @Uueerdo - That is the question I'm asking... I can only pass m and y to a subquery, I can't use m or y in the where clause of the same query due to order of sql execution

Comment: @Matt You don't get errors referring to `m` and `y` in the subquery? Result field aliases typically are only available in the HAVING clause of a query.

Comment: @Uueerdo No I don't, example SELECT NOW() as d, (SELECT d) as d2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? *(Assumes closing date is a datetime)*

```
SELECT MONTH(L_ClosingDate) as m, YEAR(L_ClosingDate) as y
   , count(*) as total
FROM contracts
WHERE L_ClosingDate >= LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) + 1 DAY
   AND L_CLosingDate < LAST_DAY(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY m, y
ORDER BY y DESC, m DESC
;
```

Comment: This answer seems really close. I'm updating the question by adding more detail to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I think this is the answer. Is there a reason why you only use L_ClosingDate? Should it be where L_ClosingDate... and L_ContractDate

Comment: I marked this as the answer because it works and the results are correct, but it doesn't work when there is a L_ContractDate set and the L_ClosingDate is 0000-00-00 which is my case for a few contracts. I Really appreciate your answer, Uueerdo

Comment: @Matt, I didn't notice the L_ContractDate. That could complicate things, perhaps modifying the WHERE like so `WHERE ([closing date stuff]) OR ([same stuff but to contract data])` would help.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way of solve this is create a `months` table, and that is easy to do because only take 1200 rows for whole century.

```
CREATE TABLE months (
   month_id  int,
   beginDay  date,
   lastDay   date
)
```

Then your query become much more simple. Just join and calculate `between`